# SilverStripe: how do I make a field conditionally required (or the form unsubmittable)?

Tags: javascript, forms, silverstripe, required

In SilverStripe (3.1.4) I'm doing a complex admin interface for one of my DataObject, where - depending on the DropDown's selected option - one or two TextFields get disabled or enabled for admin input. What I still need to do is to make the appropriate fields required when they get enabled.

I tried the following code which attempts to hook up to the Save button action:

```
(function ($) {
    $.entwine('ss', function () {
        $('#Form_ItemEditForm_action_doSave').entwine({
            onclick: function (e) {
                alert('submitting')
                var selectedItem = $('#Form_ItemEditForm_Symbol option:selected').text();
                if (selectedItem.indexOf('%1') > -1 && $.trim($('#Form_ItemEditForm_Placeholder1').val()) == '') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This does not seem to work - the form still submits, the alert never shows up.

Is there anything I'm missing?

---

I also tried to add:

```
Behaviour.register({
    '#Form_ItemEditForm' : {
        initialize : function() {
            this.observeMethod('BeforeSave', this.beforeSave);
        },

        beforeSave: function() {
            alert("You clicked save");
        }
    }
});
```

But ever since the form has not been loading at all.

Comment: well probable not the answer you were looking for but I used the following in such cases: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic

Comment: In fact, it does not dynamically set "required" but thanks for the pointer - I filed a feature enhancement issue. Also, I like learning by peeking into other modules' code.